# MySQL - different description in table with ids from the same table

Tags: mysql

i have these tables:

tb_employee:

```
ID       EMPLOYEE
1      Jhonatan Sandoval
2      Patricia Sanchez
3       Ken Dawson
```

tb_bankacc:

```
ID         BANK         AMOUNT        OWNER (from tb_employee)
1         Bank 1        250000                  1
```

tb_pay:

```
ID            OWNER          EMPLOYEE             AMOUNT
1               1              2                    500
2               1              3                    480
```

I need to make a `SELECT QUERY` to show the names of employees, like this:

```
ID                 OWNER                       EMPLOYEE                 AMOUNT
1             Jhonatan Sandoval              Patricia Sanchez            500
2             Jhonatan Sandoval                Ken Dawson                480
```

But, i don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT p.Id, o.Employee AS Owner, e.Employee, p.Amount
FROM tb_pay p
INNER JOIN tb_employee e ON e.Id = p.Employee
INNER JOIN tb_employee o ON o.Id = p.Owner
```

You're joining to the `tb_employee` table twice, once to get the names for the `Employee` column (by joining the Id in the `Employee` column with the `Id` in `tb_employee` - and then taking the name from that record) and then again to get the names for the `Owner` column (joining the Id in the `Owner` column to the `Id` in `tb_employee`).